# difference between "will you be -ing?" and "are you -ing?"

Tags: expressions

Are there any differences among the following:

1. Are you using this room tomorrow?
2. Will you be using this room tomorrow?
3. Will you use this room tomorrow?

1  and 3 seem to be asking someone’s intention to use the room, while 2 has nothing to do with someone’s intention or will.

It is simply asking if the room has been booked for the person being asked, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between any of these constructions. Indeed, you might add two more, which mean the same thing:

> Are you going to be using ...?
>   Are you going to use ... ?

There is no reason to select one over another (but in context whatever forms were used immediately before the question might affect the choice).

With respect to modality, these are all about as mode-neutral as any *question* about the *future* can be. None of these questions addresses the interlocutor's "intention" or "will": all of them treat the room's status for tomorrow simply as a determined fact known to the interlocutor.

The interlocutor's *intention* would probably only come into play if that intention stood in contrast to some other fact; in this case the speaker would probably employ different verbs in her question, depending on the exact situation:

> *Are you planning/Do you plan* to use ...? *OR*
>   *Are you intending/Do you intend* to use ...?  *OR*
>   *Have you decided* to use ...? *OR*
>   *Do you want/need* to use this room tomorrow?  —because I don't think it's been booked yet.

(These are of course examples which don't exhaust the possibilities.)